# Hooks when seeding objects

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, hook, seeding

In my model code, I encrypt the user's password with the hook `beforeCreate`.

In a seeder I'm creating 10 users with `queryInterface.bulkInsert`.

As I've understood it, hooks are bypassed when using `bulkInsert`.

How can I seed the database with 10 users AND use hooks like the one mentioned?

File: seeders/20180917155607-users.js

```
import faker from 'faker'
import lodash from 'lodash'

export default {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const res = lodash.times(10, () => ({
      email: faker.internet.email(),
      password: 'Password',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    }))
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('users', res, {})
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    // do your stuff
  }
}
```

File: models/user.js

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  })
  User.beforeCreate(async user => {
    user.password = await user.generatePasswordHash()
  })

  User.prototype.generatePasswordHash = async function() {
    const saltRounds = 10
    return await bcrypt.hash(this.password, saltRounds)
  }
  return User
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `beforeBulkCreate`?

Comment: @MikeGorski Any suggestion how that would be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are: 
1. queryInterface methods which do not use the model, hence no
hooks. bulkInsert() is a queryInterface method.
2. model methods bulkCreate is a model method and will fire the beforeBulkCreate hook. If you pass the individualHooks: true option it will fire both the beforeBulkCreate and the beforeCreate hooks for you.
3.The docs say that bulkInsert takes same options option as bulkCreate, which would include individualHooks, and transactions. Looking at the code for model.js shows that bulkCreate actually does it work via returning a builkInsert call so it should work. I have been unable to achieve that so far.

Answer (score 0):

To run hooks with `bulkInsert()`/`bulkCreate()` you need to pass in the [`individualHooks`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate) option (include `validate` to run validations).

```
queryInterface.bulkInsert('users', res, {
  validate: true, 
  individualHooks: true,
});
```